# Converting Scala hmacSHA256 encryption to Nodejs crypto

Tags: java, node.js, scala, encryption, cryptography

I've this encryption method in Scala, which I want to convert to NodeJS for a microservice:

```scala
val key = "very-secret-key"
val id1 = "1001"
val id2 = "2002"
val id3 = "3003"

val mac = Mac.getInstance("hmacSHA256")
mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes, "hmacSHA256"))
val digest = mac.doFinal(id1.getBytes ++ id2.getBytes ++ id3.getBytes)

new String(UrlBase64.encode(digest)).replace(".", "")
```

tried to do this with `createHmac` from `crypto` and converting to Bytes with `Buffer` but the output token is not the same as in the one I generate in Java

```js
import { createHmac } from 'crypto';

const id1 = Buffer.from('1001', 'base64');
const id2 = Buffer.from('2002', 'base64');
const id3 = Buffer.from('3003', 'base64');

const buffer = Buffer.from("very-secret-key", 'base64');
const token = createHmac('sha256', buffer).digest('base64').replace('.', '');
```

I'm stuck trying to figure how to add the buffer bytes to the token `mac.doFinal(id1.getBytes ++ id2.getBytes ++ id3.getBytes)`

Comment: The first snippet does not seem to be Java, but Scala.

Comment: @Topaco yes my bad, I just realized that I wrote Java instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of `id1`, `id2`, `id3` and `buffer`/`key` differs in both codes. In the Scala code, the `getBytes` method is applied, which uses the default platform encoding. In the NodeJS code the same encoding must be applied instead of Base64.
E.g. assuming that the default platform encoding in the Java environment is UTF-8:

```js
const id1 = Buffer.from('1001', 'utf8');
const id2 = Buffer.from('2002', 'utf8');
const id3 = Buffer.from('3003', 'utf8');
const buffer = Buffer.from("very-secret-key", 'utf8');
```

Furthermore, the NodeJS code is missing the `update()` calls that pass the `id1`, `id2` and `id3` data. Also, for the encoding of the HMAC Base64url must be used instead of Base64 to be compatible with the Scala code:

```js
const token = crypto.createHmac('sha256', buffer)
  .update(id1)
  .update(id2)
  .update(id3)
  .digest('base64url');
```

Since the Base64url alphabet does not contain `.`, the `replace('.', '')` call is actually not necessary (neither in the Scala nor in the NodeJS code).

With these changes, both codes return the same HMAC for the same input data, e.g. for the posted inut data `B5WtlMrLxvMMcDqxOls0-qxqGW2bbaOanXLE7RaXAbA` (assuming UTF-8 as default platform encoding in the Java environment).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.
I made just a slight adjustment, instead of doing `.update()` multiple times, I've used `update(Buffer.concat([id1, id2, id3]))`